# Spring boot login using Facebook throws authorization_request_not_found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-session

I'm implementing login using Facebook with Spring Boot, Spring Session and Spring Security OAuth2. My application runs on a local machine and I am using a selfed-sign certificate. I'm using header-based authentication and not using JSESSIONID cookie. I'm saving sessions in the database.

Now, when I trying to login using Facebook it gives me this error:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [authorization_request_not_found] 
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:163)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:141)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

My configuration looks likes this:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final UserPrincipalDetailsService userPrincipalDetailsService;
    private final CustomOath2UserService customOath2UserService;
    private final OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    private final OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;

    public SecurityConfiguration(UserPrincipalDetailsService userPrincipalDetailsService,
                                 CustomOath2UserService customOath2UserService,
                                 OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler,
                                 OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler) {
        this.userPrincipalDetailsService = userPrincipalDetailsService;
        this.customOath2UserService = customOath2UserService;
        this.oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler = oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
        this.oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler = oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth2/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v1/user/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v1/user/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v1/user/exists").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .cors()
                .and().csrf()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                    .userInfoEndpoint().userService(customOath2UserService)
                    .and()
                    .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler);
        ;
    }

    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider dap = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        dap.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        dap.setUserDetailsService(userPrincipalDetailsService);
        return dap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcHttpSession
public class SessionConfig extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer {

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionIdResolver() {
        return HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken();
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, "/");
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response,
                                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println(authentication.getName());
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class CustomOath2UserService extends DefaultOAuth2UserService {
    @Override
    public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        return new CustomOauth2User(super.loadUser(userRequest));
    }
}
```

When I'm removing **SessionConfig** class everything works fine. Can I implement Facebook login using  header-based authentication?

Comment: to my knowledge, authentication using oauth2 is stateless and therefore sessionless. You always need to provide the token because there is no session, hence no session Id. xAuthToken is the session id, which there should be none. But im just guessing here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I switch HttpSessionIdResolver to cookie-based it works fine and after redirecting it automatically opens the session

Answer (score 3):

As the exception states the OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter can't retrieve the authorization request. Because by default it uses the HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository which tries to retrieve the original authorization request sent to the Authorization Server from the requests session.

When the Auth server returns the Authorization code, it uses the redirect uri, and goes through the users browser, thats like a separate request, if you use cookies the users browser will automatically include any that were created for the domain of the redirect uri, which will include the original session cookie, but browsers don't work with headers like that so when the request hits spring, there is no cookie or header to identify the session so a new one is created and that session won't have the original auth request on it, and Spring needs that to confirm the state parameter matches what the auth server sent it to protect against CSRF.

Unfortunately there is no out of the box implementation from spring yet, there is an open issue to get another repository added https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6374
Basically you need to create a custom AuthorizationRequestRepository that stores and retrieves the authorization request somehow. You could use a non session cookie to store the auth request and use the repository to retrieve it from there, or a database or some custom in memory solution.
You can add it:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
.oauth2Login()
.authorizationEndpoint()
.authorizationRequestRepository(.....................
```

You could also customize the state parameter sent in the original authorization request like add a JWT to it, (as long as it is always unique), the authoirzation server will send it back with the auth code, and the JWT could include the state info you need to identify the original auth request and any state info you need to manage the state outside of a session.

Answer (score 2):

In our case the JSESSIONID Cookie was not sent when referring back to the login/oauth2/code/?code=... URL because the Cookie had the SameSite = Strict policy and the browser would not send it because of this policy.